# How to fix multiple click on button (database quiz application)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, button

I applied a question about firebase. There are buttons in the question and answer section. But when there is continuous clicks, the answers to the next questions are also clicked. How can I solve this?

this is QuestionActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        qCount = findViewById(R.id.question_num);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.coundown);

        option1 = findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2 = findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3 = findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4 = findViewById(R.id.option4);

        option1.setOnClickListener(this);
        option2.setOnClickListener(this);
        option3.setOnClickListener(this);
        option4.setOnClickListener(this);
```

this is OnClick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int selectedOption = 0;


        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;

            case R.id.option2:
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.option3:
                selectedOption = 3;

                break;
            case R.id.option4:
                selectedOption = 4;

            default:

        }
        //  countdown.cancel();
        checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);


    }
```

and this is Question.java

```
public class Question {

    String question;
    String optionA;
    String optionB;
    String optionC;
    String optionD;
    int correctAns;


    public Question(String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC, String optionD, int correctAns) {
        this.question = question;
        this.optionA = optionA;
        this.optionB = optionB;
        this.optionC = optionC;
        this.optionD = optionD;
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions to this.
At the beginning of your onClick class put

```
    option1.setOnClickListener(null);
    option2.setOnClickListener(null);
    option3.setOnClickListener(null);
    option4.setOnClickListener(null);
```

and then reassign the onClickListeners when you want to ask another question.

Or you could do this:

```
boolean questionBeingAsked = true;
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int selectedOption = 0;


if(questionBeingAsked){

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.option1:
            selectedOption = 1;
            break;

        case R.id.option2:
            selectedOption = 2;
            break;

        case R.id.option3:
            selectedOption = 3;

            break;
        case R.id.option4:
            selectedOption = 4;

        default:

    }
    //  countdown.cancel();
questionBeingAsked = false;
    checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);
}

}
```

and then when you want to ask a question just run:

```
questionBeingAsked = true;
```